# getRunningTasks() causing error even with get permission

Tags: android

Android studio , is giving me some issues. I clearly declared android. permission.GET_TASKS in the manifest. But it still closes the app.
Error:

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getTasks() from   pid=1010, uid=10046 requires android.permission.GET_TASKS`

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>


>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2"></activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".LockScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lock_screen"
        >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: version of your testing device?

Comment: API 18 android emulator

Comment: permissions should not be inside the application tag. move it outside

Comment: Then it says that its deprecated

Comment: because it is in API21.

Comment: cant I make it run on all apis but 21

Comment: deprecated does not mean that you can't use it.

Comment: So will it still run on everything without api 21

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html keyword is `discouraged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your permission Tag outside of Application Tag

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<application 
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
<!--Elements inside application Tag-->
</application>
```